# Why does my canvas disappear after making a text field entry?

Tags: python, canvas, text, tkinter

I'm trying to make a hangman game and allow the users to enter a value to draw the hangman. Though it's not complete yet, I'm having an issue when applying a textfield onto my second canvas. Whenever I implement my text field onto the second canvas, the text field shows up but the canvas disappears and only the hangman appears. I want to have the textfield appear on top of the second canvas. Anyone know why or suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.wm_title("HangMan")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=800)
canvas.pack()

canvas2 = Canvas(root, bg="lightblue",height=400, width=800)
canvas2.pack()

text1 = canvas.create_text(15,15,anchor = "nw")
canvas.itemconfig(text1, text = "Press Up, Down, Left, or Right")


#Creates the pole
a = canvas.create_rectangle(550,50,550,350,fill = "black")
b = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,550,50,fill = "black")
c = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,350,90,fill = "black")

e = Entry(canvas2)
e.pack()

e.delete(0,END)
e.insert(0, "enter a integer")

#Creates man
d = canvas.create_oval(325, 90, 375, 140, outline = "black") #head
e = canvas.create_line(350, 140, 350, 230, fill = "black") #neck and torso
f = canvas.create_line(300, 125, 350, 175, fill = "black") #left arm
g = canvas.create_line(400, 125, 350, 175, fill = "black") #right arm
h = canvas.create_line(350, 230, 310, 300, fill = "black") #left leg
i = canvas.create_line(350, 230, 390, 300, fill = "black") #right leg


root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

I now implemented the create_window method and now it works!

```
e = Entry(canvas2)

canvas2.create_window(100, 100, window = e)

e.delete(0,END)
e.insert(0, "enter a integer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pack`, the default behavior is for the containing widget (in this case, a canvas) to "shrink to fit". So, the canvas is disappearing because it shrinks to be just big enough to contain the entry.

Typically, if you're adding an entry widget to a canvas you'll want to use the `create_window` method of the canvas. You can turn off the "shrink to fit" feature (with a method called `overrideredirect`) but it very rarely is the right solution. Without knowing more about the effect you're trying to create by using two canvases, it's difficult to recommend the correct solution.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for the advise. I implemented the create_window method and it works now!                                                                                  `e = Entry(canvas2)

canvas2.create_window(100, 100, window = e)

e.delete(0,END)
e.insert(0, "enter a integer")`